# awk: how to delete first and last value on entire column

Tags: awk

I have a data that is comprised of several columns. On one column I would like to delete two commas that are each located in beginning and the end of entire column. My data looks something like this:

```
a    ,3,4,3,2,
b    ,3,4,5,1,
c    ,1,5,2,4,5,
d    ,3,6,24,62,3,54,
```

Can someone teach me how to delete the first and last commas on this data? I would appreciate it.

Comment: Can you post how you'd like the data to look in the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '{sub(/,/,"",$0); print substr($0,0,length($0)-1)}'  input.txt
```

Output:

```
a    3,4,3,2,
b    3,4,5,1,
c    1,5,2,4,5,
d    3,6,24,62,3,54
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk '{gsub(/^,|,$/,"",$NF)}1' file
a 3,4,3,2
b 3,4,5,1
c 1,5,2,4,5
d 3,6,24,62,3,54
```

Comment: +1: This is good though output appears to loose the spaces between first and second column

Comment: Yup, it's just recompiling $0 with OFS between fields courtesy of modifying a field. Usually not a problem or easily worked around if it is.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with `sed` too:

```
sed -e 's/,//' -e 's/,$//' file
```

That says "substitue the first comma on the line with nothing" and then "substitute a comma followed by end of line with nothing".

If you want it to write a new file, do this:

```
sed -e 's/,//' -e 's/,$//' file > newfile.txt
```

Comment: +1 for simplicity. To make it convoluted, one could do `sed -r ':a;s/ ,|,$//;ta' file` (using `gnu sed`).